# What is the distance the COVID-19 virus can travel in the air out of doors and remain infectious for someone breathing the same air?

Tags: covid-19, disease-transmission, infectious-diseases, airborne-transmission

I edited my question after doing some research. I also edited the question to include phrase "out of door". When indoors the risk is increased considerable with stale air or air that has been circulated from another area that may have the virus. I edited the question to be more specific although it may still need improvement. I am also not sure of the tags.

The measles can be transmitted up to 30 meters and remain airborne up to 2 hours thus far COVID-19 remains I believe an open issue.

Comment: There have been lots of studies done.  Did your research not find any?

Comment: According to [this March 2020 article](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/fullarticle/2763852), "no studies have directly evaluated the biophysics of droplets and gas cloud formation for patients infected with the SARS-CoV-2 virus". But the author, MIT Prof Lydia Bourouiba, says exhalations can cause gaseous clouds that travel up to 27 feet.

Comment: @unutbu You could turn that comment into a good answer.

Comment: @CareyGregory May I know why did you rejected my suggested edit to this post?

Comment: @America Because you added four tags that I didn't think added value (eg, breathing).

Comment: @CareyGregory So this tags don't add value: `covid-19`, `infectious-diseases`, `research` and `breathing` + changing COVID19 to COVID-19

Comment: @America The breathing and research tags are so broad as to be worthless and adding a dash to COVID19 seemed trivial. If you want to re-edit, I'll approve if you just leave out breathing and research.

Comment: Sir, with the new information you could answer your own question (including the links)

Comment: @America ...you are spot on ...an open issue and that is the answer. This has been an open question since one of the first outbreaks with the Choir practice fiasco in Washington State or Oregon, can't recall which and hasn't changed in four months. Maybe airborne maybe not maybe so but a controversial topic thusfar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this March 2020 article](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/fullarticle/2763852), "no studies have directly evaluated the biophysics of droplets and gas cloud formation for patients infected with the SARS-CoV-2 virus". But the author, MIT Prof Lydia Bourouiba, says exhalations can cause gaseous clouds that travel up to 27 feet.

Comment: Good answer, but gaseous clouds and particle-containing clouds are different things. There are lots of studies in progress, and they are alarming. Viral particles remain suspended in the air after invasive procedures for hours (depending on the study, two to four hours), and a forceful cough can propel smaller droplets - virus-laden droplets - up to 15 feet.